# How can I access the paragraph fields from my node via Tokens?

Tags: tokens, paragraphs

Token Version: 8.x-1.7
Paragraphs Version: 8.x-1.12

I have one main node. In this main node I have referenced another sub-node. This sub-node has two fields with paragraphs. Each of these paragraphs consists of further text fields.
I would like to access these fields in the pargraphs by token. Unfortunately, I cannot find a suitable token for this. Neither in my token browser nor under /admin/help/token .

The only token with which I can access the field is the following:
[node:field_agent_reference:entity:field_gratification_for_agents].

But unfortunately this only gives me the whole content of the paragraph and not the fields individually. What am I doing wrong?

All other tokens that start with paragraphs, such as:
[paragraph:field_agent:entity:field_gratification_fur_agents]
[paragraph:field_agent:entity:field_bonus_number_or_percent]
[paragraph:field_percentage_media]
[paragraph:field_percentage_media:value]

do not function for me.

Thanks a lot

Bavra

Answer (score 1):

The token browser stops spitting out chained suggestions after a sensible level of nesting - otherwise the memory use and (lack of) UI responsiveness could easily get out of hand. That doesn't mean that chaining stops, just the available hints.

You can keep right on going, e.g.

```
[node:field_agent_reference:entity:field_gratification_for_agents:entity:field_foo:value]
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your feedback. So I have now tried the following, without result:
[node:field_agentur_reference:entity:field_gratifikation_fur_agenten:entity:0:field_auszahlung:value]

[node:field_agentur_reference:entity:field_gratifikation_fur_agenten:entity:0:field_auszahlung]

[node:field_agentur_reference:entity:field_gratifikation_fur_agenten:entity:field_auszahlung:value]

[node:field_agentur_reference:entity:field_gratifikation_fur_agenten:0:entity:field_auszahlung:value]

[node:field_agentur_reference:entity:field_gratifikation_fur_agenten:0:entity:field_auszahlung]

The machine name of the paragraph is:   gratifikation_fur_agenten
The machine name of the two fields in the paragraph is:
field_auszahlung
field_prozent
both from type number(integer)

Thnx

Answer (score 0):

I would like to change the depth/recursion of the token browser for a moment. I know about the risk.

I have played with the following settings in the token.module, but nothing has happened yet:

```
'token_types' => [],
  'global_types' => TRUE,
  'click_insert' => TRUE,
  'show_restricted' => TRUE,
  'show_nested' => TRUE,
  'recursion_limit' => 8,
  'text' => NULL,
  'options' => [],
```

Did I miss something?
Thank you and greetings

Bavra